# Rails how to add product to profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a library of documents that I have created, user can browse and then add it to their profile so that they can view and read it later.

So basically its like adding to cart thing, but here I just want them to add to their profile and read than browsing again.

I am new to rails and I've seen that many times things I do for a week is already available as gem so is there any gem for this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like between users and documents there is many to many relation, for that you need to create a table `document_users`, columns will be `document_id` and `user_id`

in User.rb

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :document_users
  has_many :documents, :through => :document_users
end
```

in document_user.rb

```
Class DocumentUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :document
  belongs_to :user
end
```

in Document.rb

```
Class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :document_users
  has_many :users, :through => :document_users
end
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. And since only the admin will add/remove the document (which is a collection of questions(another model) ). I was wondering if there is any gem for this kind of functionality or customising any gems will help.

Comment: you can set user roles by using CanCan gem, here is an awesome video tutorial from ryan http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan